# Shifting characters in a word list in R

Tags: r, character, purrr, stringr, substr

I have a set of 5 random words in a list: "House", "Book", "Appreciate", "Cherry", "Computer"
I want to use a function that shift the letters in the word to the left by a random integer x from 1:4, so if x=2, "House" will be shift left and it will be "useHo". If x=4, "Appreciate" will become "reciateAppr".

The code I have seems to shift the letters to the right, but not left. If x is greater than the length of the word, it will produce an error such at if x=3 for the word "Of", then it should return an error.

```
library(purrr)

wordlist <- c("House", "Book", "Appreciate", "Cherry", "Computer", "Of")

shift <- function(list, x){
  x <- sample(1:6,6)
  x <- x%%nchar(list)
  paste0(substr(list,nchar(list)-x+1,nchar(list)), substr(list,1,nchar(list)-x))
}

map(wordlist, shift)
```

Comment: To make debugging easier, I would recommend writing ` shift` function that just shifts letters by an input amount, and then wrapping it in another function that does the randomness.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `sub` here for a base R regex option:

```r
wordShift <- function(n, wordlist) {
    regex <- paste0("^(.{", n, "})(.*)$")
    sub(regex, "\\2\\1", wordlist)
}

wordlist <- c("House", "Book", "Appreciate", "Cherry", "Computer", "Of")
wordShift(2, wordlist)

[1] "useHo"      "okBo"       "preciateAp" "erryCh"     "mputerCo"
[6] "Of"
```

In the case of shifting by 2, the regex used here is:

```regex
"^(.{2})(.*)$"
```

We then replace with `\2\1`, thereby moving the first 2 characters to the end of each word.

Comment: What if I don't specify the numbers of characters to shift and I need it to be a random number from 1 to 5?

Comment: Use: `sample.int(5, 1)`